# Saving an image in MYSQL vs saving to a folder

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an advantage to either method and/or a risk to either? Looking to upload JPG or PNG files only with a size limit of ~3mb with reduction done before insertion.

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with uploading images? Are you asking about uploading a MySQL database versus uploading the files directly?

Comment: @Ixrec If I understood right, the question is about saving the image data inside the database, rather than saving it in a filesystem and having the database store a reference to the image's filesystem location instead.

Comment: @Kev Yes correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep them out of the database, store them in the OS's file system and just store a relative path in a database table.

This will allow you to lazy load any images, queries will remain snappy, your database would remain small and image files may be backed up easily. You will have two data stores though and will have to make sure they stay in sync. A modern RDBMS may have solid support for large files so it may be quicker/easier to store them in the database.

So it would depend on your application, how much trust you have in your database and the feature set of your database. And personal preference.

Comment: What is the speed of mysql and what is the speed of the folder, @Martin Maat